# Code works fine on my system but causes a stack smashing error when i submit it to the bot that is supposed to check it

Tags: c, stack

This program at this stage is supposed to get text from the user and separate it into paragraphs, sentences and words. The code works fine so far on my system(ubuntu 18.04) but when i submit it to the bot that is supposed to give input to it, a stack smashin error comes up. Is there a way to make my code read input without crashing?

Edit:
Here's a test input. I think the problem is that it reads it all at once.(also there are some other options apart from ap: that i haven't made yet):

Test 3 Input: ap:At the center of the novel is the typical 
   Graham Greene character.[
 ]fw:h[
 ]fs:ovel[ ]fp:typical[
 ]owf[
 ]owl[
 ]ap:He is tired 
   and skeptical, basically decent yet cynical. One senses
  that life has no real colors to him, in fact it bores him, yet 
   there is an underlying hope of some redemption, of some 
   sense of meaning.[
 ]fw:or[
 ]fw:is[
 ] 
  owf[
 ]owl[
 ]qt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void ap(char ***p, char ***s, char ***w, int *n_p, int *n_s, int *n_w)
{
    char *temp = malloc(10001 * sizeof(char));
    int i, k, j, length;

    if(temp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory");
        return;
    }
    fgets(temp, 10001, stdin);
    while(temp[0] == ' ')
        for(i = 0;i < strlen(temp);i++)
            temp[i] = temp[i + 1];

    //paragraphs
    *n_p += 1;
    **p = realloc(**p, *n_p * sizeof(char *));
    *(*p + *n_p - 1) = malloc((strlen(temp) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if(**p == NULL || *(*p + *n_p - 1) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory");
        return;
    }
    strcpy(*(*p + *n_p - 1), temp);

    //sentences
    while(temp[0] != '\0')
    {
        k = strcspn(temp, ".!?;");
        length = strlen(temp);
        temp[k] = '\0';
        *n_s += 1;
        **s = realloc(**s, *n_s * sizeof(char *));
        *(*s + *n_s - 1) = malloc((strlen(temp) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if(**s == NULL || *(*s + *n_s - 1) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Could not allocate memory");
            return;
        }
        strcpy(*(*s + *n_s - 1), temp);
        j = 0;
        for(i = k + 1;j <= length - k;i++)
        {
            temp[j] = temp[i];
            j++;
        }
        while(temp[0] == ' ')
            for(i = 0;i < strlen(temp);i++)
                temp[i] = temp[i + 1];
        k = strcspn(temp, "\n");
        while(temp[k + 1] == ' ')
            for(i = k;i < strlen(temp);i++)
                temp[i] == temp[i + 1];
        if(!(strcmp(*(*s + *n_s - 1), "\n")))
        {
            free(*(*s + *n_s - 1));
            *n_s -= 1;
        }
     }
}

int main()
{
    char **paragraphs, **sentences, **words, option[5];
    int num_par = 0, num_sent = 0, num_words = 0, i;

    paragraphs = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    sentences = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    words = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    if(paragraphs == NULL || sentences == NULL || words == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory");
        return 1;
    }

    do
    {
        scanf("%s", option);
        if(!(strcmp(option, "ap:")))
            ap(&paragraphs, &sentences, &words, &num_par, &num_sent, &num_words);
    }
    while(strcmp(option, "qt"));

    //test
    for(i = 0;i < num_par;i++)
        printf("%s", paragraphs[i]);
    printf("-------------  %d\n", num_sent);
    for(i = 0;i < num_sent;i++)
        printf("%s\n", sentences[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Part of debugging is creating an MRR (Minimal Reproducable Example).

Comment: You could try running it through Valgrind yourself, but without providing some sort of test input this isn't reproducable.

Comment: You know that in `for(i = 0;i < strlen(temp)...` the `strlen` function is called on _each_ iteration, wasting lots of CPU cycles?

Comment: When does this loop end? `while(temp[0] == ' ')`? And what do you change if that condition is true?

Comment: I have seen this code yesterday. It was deemed overly complex and suggestions were given.I don't see anything of those suggestions.

Comment: Like `size_t nspace = 0; while(temp[nspace] == ' ') nspace++; memmove (temp, &temp[nspace], nspace);` and be done trimming leading whitespace... Not to mention the *Statement Without Effect* : `temp[i] == temp[i + 1];`?, did you mean `=`?

Comment: I appreciate all the feedback guys. And Paul i know there were some improvements suggested for my code but they used a bit too advanced stuff that i haven't been taught yet. This is my semester project and we are supposed to complete it only with what was covered by our professor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`option` is too small, the line:

```
scanf("%s", option);
```

Tries to read each line into a 5 character array. Lines that are more than 5 characters overflow the array and gcc catches it with a canary and kills you for stack smashing.

It might run if your local compiler doesn't implement stack smashing detection.

Increase `char option[x]` to some reasonable value of x for your line lengths.