# Having trouble with a c program that separates strings into paragraphs. sentences and words

Tags: c, string, pointers

The program needs to get input text and an option from the user. At this stage I am currently working on the ap: option which reads a text from the user and appends the corresponding data to the corresponding arrays. (Also I have to input the text with the option as a prefix, e.g. ap:Text, because that is how the bot that tests my program inputs it.).

Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/Kritsos/03d08f29beb97d24eba1cbc4e83962ab

I know it's a bit difficult to follow it so I will try to explain it as better as I can. First of all I know that there are a lot of memory leaks, I will tend to them as soon as I get the 3 functions working. I have tried to dynamically allocate almost everything (that's why I use triple pointers) and I hope that the allocation is correct and not the cause of the problems. The par function is supposed to get a paragraph from the input text which is easy because the input texts is a paragraph on its own so I just copy the text to the paragraph array. Now the sent and word functions are the ones I am having trouble with. Both are based on the same logic. I take the input text from the user, I try to find the ending character( ".!?;" for sentences " " for words), place a '\0' there, copy the string to the corresponding array then do the same thing but instead of checking the whole input text again I start from the position I placed the '\0' + 1.

Comment: I feel like this homework assignment is causing this class a lot of trouble https://stackoverflow.com/q/59509457

Comment: It certainly is... And to think last year's project was a tic-tac-toe.

Comment: [Valgrind says](https://gist.github.com/nickelpro/b63e1176f6d756d565ac15d800e530b6) you're using unitialized values in your reallocs, but your code is too much of a gordian knot for me to figure out what's going on. You should really consider restructuring it so each function is doing much less work and is easier to reason about. Consider this: first have functions that count the number of words/sentences and return that as an integer, _then_ allocate the needed arrays, _then_ have functions to fill those arrays.

Comment: You can simplify your code by using array indexing instead of pointer gymnastics. And, once you think you need `***` pointers you should redesign into structs. Note: all your functions except `main()` return void. Why?

Comment: Because i want them to just change the contents of the arrays without returning anything. Also our professor barley mentioned structures so i have no idea how yo work with them.

Comment: I expect the next lesson to be about structs. Also: even without them you don't need triple pointers here. Just double pointers and arrays of pointers would suffice. Functions could return the amount of characters/words/paragraphs they consumed or produced. Or an error code.

Comment: Often, when triple pointers appear in your code, it is a sign that redesign is needed. As @wildplasser commented, consider using return values. Also, the result of `realloc()` should not be used directly: it may fail and lose reference to the original memory. Store the result in a temporary variable until you know that the reallocation was successful.

Comment: @exnihilo You don't care about losing the reference from a failed `realloc` if your code just exits on failure. That's the case here and is extremely common in applications

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code has numerous errors in it, the critical one that's causing your current crash are lines 8, 32, and 59. All variations on this:

```
**paragraphs = realloc(**paragraphs, *num_par * sizeof(char *));
```

You're calling realloc on pointers that were never allocated in the first place.

The lesson here isn't "be careful with pointers" or anything like that, though obviously you should be. The lesson is that tons of indirection becomes difficult to reason about. Rather than try to make a three-star solution work, you should explore a different approach that doesn't require these kinds of code gymnastics.

Comment: So i have to do all the data appending within the main function? Because the platform our code will be tested runs on a limited resources stack and i definitely have to use pointers.

Comment: There are countless ways to solve this problem, some very straight forward, others extremely esoteric. I was just cautioning you that your current approach was not an easy one, and it was worth rethinking rather than endlessly banging your head against this _particular_ implementation.

Comment: Could you provide me a with a hint about how could a freshman comp sci student go on about this problem?

Comment: @I_Hate_C [I gave this a shot on my lunch break](https://gist.github.com/nickelpro/2e454a22922759e6eb3112864c25c274), feel free to use whatever from it to stimulate some ideas about how to architect your code